# Force focus on control via xaml style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a treeview and a listbox.
I want to specify on the style trigger-setter option that, when the listbox visibility is Hidden the focus have to return on the treeview.

Is it possibile to condition an user control focus on the state of another user control?

something like

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
   <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
          <Setter Property="IsFocus" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, see the example  here

**FOR CHILDREN IN CONTAINERS**

```
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=lol}">
    <TextBox x:Name="lol"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="lul"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**FOR SELF**

```
<TextBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```